# How to add same keys and different values in object of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Let's say I have an array of objects

```
const objectArr = [{name:hello, y:3},{name:world, y:5}]
```

I want to add same key but different values for each object Like

```
const objectArr = [{name:hello, y:3, color:red},{name:world, y:5, color:yellow}]
```

So I could assign each object with a different color. This is the approach I have used so far but it assigns each object the same value

```
const h = vm.data.forEach(object => {
            object.color = 'red';
          });
```

Comment: What determines what value you should give to the property?

Comment: Create an array for colors, instead of `object.color = 'red';` use random color `object.color = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)];`

Comment: Actually for each object I have to specify one color color Like first as green second as yellow as so on

Comment: Is there a set of colours you are supposed to use? What if there are less colours than values in `objectArr`?

Comment: Yes there is a defined set of colors and data from the backend is just sending 3 object in array

Comment: If your colours are in `colorArr` then perhaps `h = vm.data.forEach((object, idx) => { object.color = colorArr[idx]; });`?

Comment: Good to hear. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a set of colors against each object in the array. You can achieve that by accessing the colors from an array based on the index.

```js
const objectArr = [{name:'hello', y:3},{name:'world', y:5}];

const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green'];

objectArr.forEach((obj, index) => {
  obj.color = colors[index]
});

console.log(objectArr);
```